# 習う学習 translation

Tags: translation, parsing

> **肝心な2年生で習う学習範囲は、1年生の時よりも当然難易度が上がっている。**

**習う**: to take lessons in; to be taught; to learn (from a teacher); to study (under a teacher); to get training in.

**学習**: study; learning; tutorial.

I am confused about how to read **肝心な2年生で習う学習範囲は**, does it mean "the scope of learning that we study in the second grade is crucial"?

Thank you for your kind guidance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

学習を習う or 習う学習 in isolation makes no sense, but we say 範囲を習う "to study a (certain) range (of topics/skills)", and thus we also say 習う範囲 "the range which they study". The phrase in question is basically 習う範囲. 学習 is another word modifying 範囲, but it is actually redundant and can be omitted without changing the meaning of the sentence.

- 学習範囲: the range (of studying)
- 習う(学習)範囲: the range which they study
- 2年生で習う(学習)範囲: the range which they study in the 2nd grade

I'm not sure whether 肝心な is modifying 2年生 only or 2年生で習う学習範囲 as a whole. It depends on the broader context.

Comment: The main point that the questioner seems to have got stuck on is that the part she quoted is all modifying the 学習範囲.

Comment: えっなんでマイナス２？　わからん・・・

Answer (score 1):

> ... how to read 肝心な2年生で習う学習範囲は, does it mean "the scope of learning that we study in the second grade is crucial"?

The basic problem is that you've tried to translate the first half of a sentence as if it's an entire sentence. I'm not sure what 学習範囲 should be in English but the entire sentence roughly means "the curriculum **learnt in the important second year of studies** is of course harder than the curriculum in the first year", so the part you've picked out of the sentence is just modifying 学習範囲 rather than being a complete statement.

Comment: I think curriculum is not fit with the sentence, since it mentioned 範囲 (the scope). I also thought about it, but after I read many examples, it seems more fit to the scope of learning/study (in English). Curriculum is a course of study, in my understanding it is a step by step learning process. I appreciate your thought though.

Comment: Sorry Amanda I don't know what a good translation for 学習範囲 is in English, but it means something like "curriculum". When I answered this question this morning, I did a short search for this term but I didn't find an easy answer. If you need a good translation for that then I can search but I don't really want to.

Comment: I think it is unusual words, and I have tried to search it myself for 2 days before I decided to ask for more references here. At least I got the idea about the general meaning, so I'm quite pleased already. Thanks.

Comment: @AmandaZhang Cool!